# How to record a macro in Excel that works on any number of rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have recorded a macro in Excel that sums B2 and C2 into D2. I clicked on the lower right corner of D2 to extend the computation onto all rows.

Now, when I use this macro on other tables, it computes always the same number of rows as in the original table.

How can I record the macro so that it recognizes the height of the table and acts accordingly?

Is this possible without VBA programming?

Comment: You won't be able to. What you can do is take the output of your recording and modify it to be applicable elsewhere

Comment: Why use a macro to enter that formula?  Why not just fill the formula all the way down in advance?

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that using the `OFFSET()` formula and avoiding a macro.

```
OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

These two give the same result.

```
=SUM(B2:C2)
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,2))
```

You could count the rows in the table and use that to feed the height of your `OFFSET` formula.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,COUNT(B:B))
```